# Distribuição viciada ao usar a função rand()

Tags: c++, random

Olá, como uso a função `rand()` com o intervalo Y ∈ [11, altura+9] e X ∈ [11, largura-1].

```
srand (time(NULL));
y=rand() % ((altura+9)-11) + 11;
x=rand() % ((largura-1)-11) + 11;

gotoXY(x, y);
cout<<"o";
```

É dessa forma assim? Está a acontecer que está a gerar muitos numeros repetidos, sendo que o intervalo deveria de ser grande

Preenche apenas este espaço num ciclo `for(;;)` em meio minuto, onde largura = 70 e altura = 25:

[image: posições geradas]

Um dos problemas é executar esse codigo em loop, caso eu tire `srand (time(NULL));`
 Já consegue gerar bem os numeros, porem se eu fechar o programa e voltar a abrir vai gerar com o mesmo padrao, o que eu nao queria isso

Comment: Qual é o valor máximo e o valor mínimo do X e do Y?

Comment: quero gerar 2 inteiros, um Y e um X.
O Y quero que o intervalo seja de [11 a altura+9]
O X quero que seja de  [ 11 a largura-1]
Largura e altura é incognita

Comment: Se for esse o caso, as fórmulas parecem estar corretas.

Comment: Isso @AndersonCarlosWoss, nao consegui escrever dessa forma

Comment: O problema é que está a gerar varios numeros iguais, nao está a aproveitar o intervalo todo

Comment: Seria algo como, y: `rand() % (altura + 9) + 11` e x: `rand() %  (largura-1) + 11`? pesquei da [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/). Não entendi o `-11` no seu código

Comment: Qual é o valor de `altura` e `largura`? Imagino que sejam pequenos, dado o `gotoXY`.

Comment: Quantas vezes você executa isso? Que tipo de números muito repetidos você está tendo?

Comment: Já editei o post, com mais informaçoes

Comment: Já sei a resposta: Você está executando o `srand (time(NULL));` dentro do `for (;;)`. Isso vai fazer ele regerar os mesmos valores sempre até que o relógio mude. Mova esta instrução para antes do `for`.

Comment: Exatamente @VictorStafusa, poderá explicar o porque de isso acontecer? Gostava de perceber

Comment: O `srand` vai usar o parâmetro para gerar uma sequência de números. A primeira chamada subsequente ao `rand()` vai obter o primeiro número dessa sequência. A segunda chamada subsequente, o segundo número, etc. No entanto, se você chamar o `srand` de novo, ele vai recomeçar uma nova sequência. Como o parâmetro que você usa no `srand` será o mesmo, vez que ele muda lentamente, ele vai reiniciar sempre na mesma sequência e com isso ficar gerando valores X e Y repetidos até que o relógio mude.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Muito obrigado pela ajuda.
Obrigado a todos que ajudaram!